# Using .map creates multiple arrays without a separator in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashmap, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to extract data from an HTML table in an HTML document.

```
document = Nokogiri::HTML(File.open("webpage.html"))
tables = document.search('table')
table = tables.first # first table in the document

document.at('table').search('tr').each do |row|
    cells = row.search('th, td').map { |cell| cell.text.strip }.values_at(0, 2) #select first and second column value
end
```

When I map the extracted text it creates many arrays, without a separator (output from print):

```
["1972", "$5,500.00"]["1973", "$5,600.00"]["1974", "$6,600.00"]["1975", "$7,400.00"]["1976", "$8,300.00"]["1977", "$9,300.00"]["1978", "$10,400.00"]
```

My goal is to have a single hash that looks like this:

```
{"1972" => "$5,500.00", "1973" => "$5,600.00", "1974" => "$6,600.00", "1975" => "$7,400.00", "1976" => "$8,300.00", "1977" => "$9,300.00", "1978" => "$10,400.00"}
```

If I were creating a nested array with the map iterator, I should be able to handle that, but whatever I am doing is creating multiple arrays with no separator (comma).

I don't even know what to call the output I am receiving when I:

```
print cells
```

Alternatively, how can I convert these multiple arrays without a separator to the hash format I desire?

Comment: There is no such thing as an array without a separator. What about `cells.to_h`?

Comment: Thanks Max, that is why I am so perplexed. I'm trying to figure out what the map iterator created if it is a bunch of arrays side by side with no separator. That might help lead me to figuring it out. When I ```print cells.to_h``` I get the error ```to_h': wrong element type String at 0 (expected array) (TypeError)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually mapping the results, you're iterating and discarding them. Perhaps you mean:

```
data = document.at('table').search('tr').map do |row|
  row.search('th, td').map { |cell| cell.text.strip }.values_at(0, 2).to_h
end
```

What will return one hash per row in an array.

Comment: Thank you tadman. You are correct, I was creating the variable at the wrong place. The ```.to_h``` caused an error in the above code, however without it I finally have the nested array I was expecting/hoping for: ```["1972", "$5,500.00"], ["1973", "$5,600.00"], ["1974", "$6,600.00"], ["1975", "$7,400.00"], ["1976", "$8,300.00"], ["1977", "$9,300.00"], ["1978", "$10,400.00"]]``` **Thank you very much**

Comment: The `to_h` was there to try and get the hash-style structure you wanted, but if arrays are fine you can use that.

Comment: That is perfect, thank you. I ran the method ```to_h``` on the data variable ```print data.to_h``` and there was a perfectly designed hash just as I was hoping. ```{"1972"=>"$5,500.00", "1973"=>"$5,600.00", "1974"=>"$6,600.00", "1975"=>"$7,400.00", "1976"=>"$8,300.00", "1977"=>"$9,300.00", "1978"=>"$10,400.00"}```

Comment: If you'd prefer those numbers as integers you can do: `data.to_h.transform_keys(&:to_i)`.